# Spinthariscope with Uranium pottery / marbles instead of Americium

Tags: experimental-physics, radiation, home-experiment

Usually home made zync sulfide spinthariscopes employ Americium 241 from smoke detectors as an alpha radiation source. Uranium glazed pottery (e g. fiestaware) and uranium 'glow in the dark' marbles emit alpha as well, at a lower rate and energy (right?). I was wondering if they are suitable for a spinthariscope as well. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if they are suitable for a spinthariscope as well.

The long and short of it is $\text{NO}$.

The 'glowing' of certain $\text{U}$ salts (mainly diuranates) is simply (chemical) **fluorescence** and has nothing to do with $\text{U}$'s feeble radioactivity, which is in any case many orders of magnitude lower than that of $^{241}\text{Am}$.

Comment: thanks. maybe I was not clear regarding how I want to use such objects. the spinthariscope has a zync sulfide screen that detects alpha particles. what I want to try is a different _emitter_ of alpha particles, uranium salt instead of Americium. the 'detector' part will stay.

Comment: *Uranium is weakly radioactive because all isotopes of uranium are unstable; the half-lives of its naturally occurring isotopes range between 159,200 years and 4.5 billion years.* (Wiki) So $\text{U}$ is very very weakly radioactive, compared to $\text{Am}$. Not a good source of $\alpha$ at all.